# Enviar mais de um valor de checkbox usando Jquery.Multiselect

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

Consegui enviar os valores de uma checkbox para o controller usando a função abaixo:

```
function InformacoesAdicionais() {
    var listOfRegiao = [];
    $.each($("#select-regiao option:selected"),
        function (index, data) {
            listOfRegiao.push($(this).val());
           
        });

    $.ajax(
        {
            async: true,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Campanha/InformacoesAdicionais',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify({ listOfRegiao: listOfRegiao }),
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.Success) {
                    
                }

            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Ocorreu um erro ao salvar os dados, tente novamente.")
            },
        });


}

<select id="select-regiao" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="Capital">Capital</option>
        <option value="Interior">Interior</option>
        <option value="Vale">Vale</option>
        <option value="Litoral">Litoral</option>

    </select>
```

Porém, preciso enviar os valores de outra checkbox na mesma função, simultaneamente. Tentei de varias maneiras porém sempre envia somente o valor da checkbox "select-regiao" , enquanto a outra fica null.

Segunda checkbox:

```
 <select id="select-canal" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="Farma">Farma</option>
        <option value="Perfumaria">Perfumaria</option>
        <option value="Alimentar">Alimentar</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Aqui `data: JSON.stringify({ listOfRegiao: listOfRegiao })` vc só tá enviando um select. Sem falar que não há nenhum checkbox no código.

Comment: Estou usando o Jquery Multiple para criar as checkbox na view. Quando o usuário marca um ou mais valores da lista, a função coleta o nome dos campos e cria um array dos valores.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui da seguinte maneira

```
 function InformacoesAdicionais() {
    var listOfRegiao = [];
    var listOfCanal = [];
    $.each($("#select-regiao option:selected"),
        function (index, data) {
            listOfRegiao.push($(this).val());
           
        });
    $.each($("#select-canal option:selected"),
        function (index, data) {
            listOfCanal.push($(this).val());

        });
    $.ajax(
        {
            async: true,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Campanha/InformacoesAdicionais',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify({ listOfRegiao: listOfRegiao, listOfCanal: listOfCanal }),
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.Success) {
                    
                }

            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Ocorreu um erro ao salvar os dados, tente novamente.")
            },
        });


}
```

Comment: Por favor, forneça detalhes adicionais em sua resposta. Como está escrita atualmente, é difícil entender sua solução.